# Union lists by content

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have 2 lists:

```
list1<a> 
list2<b>
```

I would like to merge these 2 lists without duplicates according to a property exist in a and b.
To do so I have to override the methods Equals and GetHashCode.

```
public override bool Equals(object otherInstance)
    {
        MyClass instance = otherInstance  as MyClass ;
        return (instance  != null) ? GetGuid.Equals(instance .GetGuid) : false;
    }

public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetGuid.GetHashCode();
    }
```

However, I cannot inherit class A and class B from a common base class, since they already extend other classes and multiple inheritance is invalid using C#.

Any ideas?

Comment: What would you like to get as a result? `List<object>`? If no, then you probably should introduce some common interface for A and B

Comment: show some sample input and expected output.What are those properties?

Comment: @Andrei Thanks. But interface cannot contain an implementation. What is the "big deal" to implement an common interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of ways you can get this done. I'll take a shortcut. This should work if you're using .Net 4.0 and above, If not please drop a comment I'll update my answer.

```
List<Class1> list1 = new List<Class1>();
list1.Add(new Class1());

List<Class2> list2 = new List<Class2>();
list2.Add(new Class2());

var unionList =  list1.Cast<object>()
    .Union(list2.Cast<object>(), new DynamicComparer())
    .ToList();

internal class DynamicComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        dynamic dx = x;
        dynamic dy = y;
        return dx.Guid == dy.Guid;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        dynamic dobj = obj;
        return dobj.Guid.GetHashCode();
    }
}

internal class Class1
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

internal class Class2
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}
```

Since I don't know how you implemented `GetHashCode` and `Equals` I just given a example. This should give you a idea of how to start.

**How does it works**: We're using [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface to get the job done which is used to implement custom comparison rules to find object equiality. but the problem is we don't have a common interface or base class for `Class1` and `Class2` only way to represent it as common is via `System.Object` so we implement `IEqualityComparer<object>`.

Then implementation of `Equals` is pretty simple it just converts the parameters to [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) which leverages dynamic feature of .Net4.0. then simply compare the properties or fields dynamically(no compile time failure) in this case we compare `Guid` property and that's all.

Worth noting that this may fail if the property doesn't exist in runtime rather than compile time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: how DynamicComparer is defined? as a new class?

Comment: I've added that code also. Please check that. It is a new class :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's it! Could you please edit `dynamic dy = x;` to `dynamic dy = y;` - for some reason I cannot save edits... If it is not too difficult It will be nice of you to add some documentation to the DynamicComaprer class. Something else : I get the following warning `DynamicComparer.Equals(object, object)' hides inherited member 'object.Equals(object, object)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.` What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user3165438 Fixed the typo, and to get rid of that warning you need to add `new` keyword in method declaration like this `public new bool Equals(object x, object y)`. I'll find some time to explain it.

Comment: Thanks. Can DynamicComaprer return the original type of elements in the list? I wouldn't like to get a list<object> but a specific type.

Comment: @user3165438 That's not possible my friend, because our `Class1` and `Class2` doesn't have common base class or interface. our only option is `List<Object>` :( Makes sense?

Comment: But for other's sake, that's the way : DynamicComaprer class implements IEqualityComparer<`TheCommonClass`>, and its methods gets arguments from `TheCommonClass`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3165438 Also updated my answer as promised. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple good options here. Although C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, it does support some pretty handy interfaces here. You could use IComparable or IEquatable to hand-roll your own solution, or use the LINQ Distinct method.

Another option is to use LINQ Distinct and pass an IEqualityComparer.

Have the A and B implement a common interface which contains Prop. Then:

[LINQ Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
class MyClassComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{

 public bool Equals(object otherInstance)
    {
        MyClass instance = otherInstance  as MyClass ;
        return (instance  != null) ? GetGuid.Equals(instance .GetGuid) : false;
    }

public int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetGuid.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

}

```
listA.AddRange(listB); //Need to be List<ICommonInterface> Common Interface

var distinctList = listA.Distinct(new MyClassComparer<T>());
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. It is doable if you use `IEqualityComparer<Object>`

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo. I meant to write Comparer, not Operator. This has been fixed above.

Comment: @Pat Burke,Can you give please a further guidance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user3165438 Sure, I have updated above with an example with some code.

Comment: Dude it won't work that way. there is no overload which takes a lambda

Comment: @PatBurke. Thanks, Will the B items are 'stronger' than A items or the opposite? Did you see Sriram's last comment?

Comment: Question is really unclear, but reason of downvote could be `listA.AddRange(listB)` because OP has different types in lists (but I don't understand implementation of Equals and GetHashCode then)

Comment: Sorry about that, I mixed up Distinct for a second. The correct implmenetation, using his original implementations of Equals and GetHashCode is above.